# Toggle Background Position using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, background, background-image, background-position

I am new to jQuery and I am having a bit of trouble with trying to get something working.

Basically I have a wordpress site, on each page is a different background image for the `body` tag. I want to be able to toggle on a button and then the body background image to drop about 500px.

Basically I have a hidden contact area on the top of my page, and when you click on the button (`a.contact`) the hidden contact area (`#contactArea`) is revealed by dropping down from the top, however when the contactArea drops some of my background image is hidden until you click on the button again.

What I am trying to achieve is that the background image drops (still completely visible) when the hidden contactArea is revealed, so that the background image is always visible. I hope that makes sense?!

my css code is:

```
body.page.page-id-240 {
   background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 600px no-repeat;
}
```

My current jquery is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#contactArea").css('height', '0px');

    $("a.contact").toggle( 
        function () { 
            $("#contactArea").animate({ height: "225px" }, { queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear' } )
        }, 
        function () { 
            $("#contactArea").animate({ height: "0px" }, { queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear' }) 
        } 
    ); 
});
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Can you not put your background image on #contactArea?

Comment: Thanks for your help. - no because the background image is a class (.page) assigned to the body element. The contactArea section works fine, its just it hides some of the body background-image, and I am trying to get the body background-image to drop down when the contactArea drops down on toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a.contact").toggle( 
    function () { 
        $("#contactArea").animate({ height: "225px" }, { queue:false, duration: 500,  easing: 'linear' } )
        $("body.page.page-id-240").animate({ backgroundPosition: "center 825px" });
    }, 
    function () { 
        $("#contactArea").animate({ height: "0px" }, { queue:false, duration: 500, easing: 'linear' }) 
        $("body.page.page-id-240").animate({ backgroundPosition: "center 600px" });
    } 
);
```

Comment: Hi Rory McCrossan

Thanks for your help, I tried your suggestion, however the background image still didn't move on toggle. Would I not have to include the body class somewhere (.page.page-id-240) that i have added to the body element?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had a brain fade. I've updated the answer.

Comment: tried your suggestion but still no look. The body image still doesn't move when the contactArea shows. Not sure what im doing wrong-driving me crazy. Do you think it would be possible to have two body classes and on toggle a different class would be shown. so you would have: class1)body.page.page-id-240 {
   background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 600px no-repeat;
}  and then class2) body.page.page-id-240 {
   background:url(images/main-home-bg.jpg) center 900px no-repeat;
}